# Unable to delete Skype contacts

Tags: skype

Very simple question that is proving to be infuriatingly difficult to solve for me. Is there a way to delete a skype contact? [This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/how-do-i-delete-contacts-from-skype/de29af60-eec2-4366-9e3c-8f600d2ffe94) does not solve it for me. In fact, I don't ever even see an option to 'Delete contact'. When I go to my contact list (on the desktop version) and right click on a contact, all I see are the two options 'Add contact' and 'View profile' and the latter does not offer any way to delete the contact.

I am using Skype Desktop version 8.58.0.98

Comment: Please edit your question, to include if you are you using the desktop or UWP version of Skype.  Please also indicate what version of Skype you are using.

Comment: You suggest you are using Skype Desktop and the option to delete IS there. Maybe uninstall Skype and reinstall it.

Comment: Not really, I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: The version you are using is Current and what I am using, So I do not know why right click is so limited to you. Try a different Windows User profile to see if your issue is user profile related.

Comment: If I try the UWP version (which I assume to be the one from the Microsoft store) most (but not all) of the accounts from the desktop version don't appear there.

Comment: And unlike with the desktop version, it appears to be possible to remove one of those few remaining contact from the UWP version

Comment: When I look at the [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/how-do-i-delete-contacts-from-skype/de29af60-eec2-4366-9e3c-8f600d2ffe94) I used in my OP, I read "*Delete a contact: Sign in to Skype > Right-click on the contact that needs to be removed and choose Delete contact (You will only see this option if they are not in your synced mobile device address book as well)." Maybe the part in parantheses has something to do with it. How could I remove that to see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution for the same problem on iPad will be helpfull.

In the iPad app I see two list ‘my contacts’ and ‘contacts all’.
In my contacts there are only used/recent ones, but in ‘Contacts all’ there are ones imported or somehow synced with your address book. Even though after all the sync contacts is off, previously found ones remain there on the list and there is almost no way to get rid of them.

However this worked for me:

Add the contact and then delete it. I should disappear for good from both lists. Unfortunately I could not find the way to make it in mass. Just one by one ... but it works!